# Request pathway from a linkerd injected deployment to a normal deployment

Tags: kubernetes, linkerd

I have many deployments in my Kubernetes cluster. How does the pathway for a HTTP/1.x request looks like from a pod injected with linkerd to another pod without linkerd injected ?

Answer (score 2):

The request will traverse the proxy in the source pod and will simply hit the destination pod directly. Shouldn't really affect anything, other than Linkerd won't be able to handle mTLS and you won't get client-side metrics on the destination.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just to confirm, will the kube-proxy be by passed in this case ?

Comment: @sap Yes, the kube-proxy is bypassed because the linkerd proxy sends the traffic directly to the destination pod using its own load balancing algorithm